# Scripting ASP with PHP, is it possible?

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am trying to use `php` inside of `ASP`. I wonder if I could do something like this

```
<% language=php
echo "Hello World";
%>
```

Any one with ideas? Can this work?

Comment: No, this won't work.

Comment: which languages can run on ASP @u_mulder? need help as soon as possible or can i run ASP and in the action area like this <form name="" id="" action="http://127.0.0.1/server/page1.php" method=post>

Comment: You can run PHP on IIS and you can post to a PHP page from a form on an ASP page.  The usual scripting language to use with Classic ASP is VBScript, the other option is JScript, (which is Microsoft's take on JavaScript).  Python used to an option if you had the ActiveState distribution installed on your server, but I'm pretty sure ActiveState no longer support this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use PHP. 
You can use VB or C#.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx

Comment: This is a question about Classic ASP.  The languages it can use are VBScript and JScript